# Percona: Analyze table doesn't work

Tags: mysql, performance, percona, tokudb

I have a Percona 5.6.28 servers with a=some TokuDB tables. The biggest table has ~120 million rows. Statics keeps changeing in the past hald year:

- At first. Analyze table with recount model toke accurate statics back
- Recenly. The statics were updated to the same value including some column as gender.

I have tried with below ways but don't work:

- Analyze table
- Drop some index and re-create
- Optimize table & Analyze table

I found a lot people had get the same problem before. Can anyone share some experience?

Comment: Try ```ALTER TABLE <<tablename>>  ENGINE=<<enginename>> ;```  i.e ALTER TABLE  mysql.user ENGINE=INNODB

Comment: I had a plan to move things to innodb which need to update a lot things. Do you have other suggestions before migrating to innodb, Jyoti?

Comment: Zak you may be running into this known issue https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-4448 which doesn't answer your moving to innodb question I know. This link mentions something you should check https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/8.0/upgrading_guide.html#id6

Comment: Hi @percona-lorraine, thanks for your link. But it's really a different problem. I can successfully analyze table but still get bad statics.